# Transpose table rows to columns without change Mysql

Tags: php

i'm a student and  i have a question about my task.
For illustration, I have a table like this

---

| NO | H(x)1 | H(x)2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0,1238 | 0,1223 |
| 2 | 0,1345 | 0,1674 |
| 3 | 0,3457 | 0,4363 |
| 4 | 0,7589 | 0,8764 |

and i want to transpose the table to be like this

---

| NO | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H(x)1 | 0,1238 | 0,1345 | 0,3457 | 0,7589 |
| H(x)2 | 0,1223 | 0,1674 | 0,4363 | 0,8764 |

i write the code like this

```
$man = 0;
foreach ($res as $row => $column) {
    foreach ($column as $row2 => $column2) {
       echo $man[$row2][$row] = $column2;
    }
}
```

but, i got error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\sp\training.php on line 313"

How to solve the error? Or is there some other way to solve the transpose of this table?

Comment: Are you sure that the $res is not nutll and is an array ?

Comment: Can you show the data for `$res`

Comment: @Dani Could you check my code in this link? drive.google.com/file/d/12AoZM38g0HHOmE91vPagezPSTad1cvsT/… Maybe, I initialized $res or the data for array incorrectly.

Comment: @Kinglish Could you check my code in this link? drive.google.com/file/d/12AoZM38g0HHOmE91vPagezPSTad1cvsT/… Maybe, I initialized $res or the data for array incorrectly.

Comment: $res is a number `$res = 1 / (1+(exp(-$hinit)));` what array are you expeting it to be?

Comment: I suggest you to name your variables correctly because you have complex code here and $value, $res won't help you get the hang of it. $res is a numerical value as @Kinglish said, it's not iterable

Comment: @Dani okay, I replace $hinit = $result and $res = $resultAktivasi. 

$result += $valueBias[$iColumn];
                                
$resultAktivasi = array(1 / (1+(exp(-$result))));

$man = 0;
foreach ($resultAktivasi as $row => $column) {
       foreach ($column as $row2 => $column2) {
               echo $man[$row2][$row] = $column2;
        }
}

Comment: @Kinglish Actually Im confused, I want to pass an array of results $result to continue the process $resultAktivasi (data remains an array) so when I transpose the data is an array. which one should i change from the code?

Comment: @ica - can you update your link to show your latest code?

Comment: @Kinglish - okey this is it 
     https://drive.google.com/file/d/12r8eqz9Zptgaheam1KsXzfW8PvtiGQNs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ica can you show the result of this query `SELECT * FROM data_hari` ?

Comment: @Dani sure . . . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zYfL-KEnphgB3VhaC2wx-icWFwnE8DYI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There should be a more easy way to do what you want to do, but can you precise what Hinit1 and Hinit2 is, and what h(x)1 and h(x)2 is ?

Comment: @Dani Hinit is the name of the formula in the Extreme Learning Machine (ELM) method and H(x) is the activation function which is a formula in the ELM method as well.

Comment: @Dani maybe this link can help to understand the process of the ELM method . . . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DntFPTajjfUo-f_Mm4VOUvIa8q-m0Gqc/view?usp=sharing